# review audit should handle "closed" questions as "bad"

Tags: bug, disputed-review-audits

I just hit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210280/how-does-string-interning-work-in-java-7) in the review.

As I was certain that it has been answered before I would have closed it as duplicate. But it turned out to be an audit that said its nothing wrong with it.

It already was closed as a dupe so no harm done, but presenting a closed question as example of a good question is... irritating.

The code that selects "good" questions for the audit should take care not to select closed questions, ever.

Comment: audits are borked.. just as always.. there's [a lot of stuff floating around concerning that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=review+audit+is%3Aq)

Comment: @Vogel612 Yeah, I know. Most of the time I don't bother, but this is so clearly off that its a bug. A question that is closed can not ever be a candidate for a "good" example.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer in which review queue did this happen?

Comment: @m0sa Guessing it was [this review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6356128), so it'd be the Close Vote queue.

Comment: @m0sa Close Votes. JonK did provide the correct link.

Comment: oh.. that's a classic case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @m0sa I see. Fine then, good to know. How long does the cache hold? I checked the answer and dismissed "cache" as problem as the close was like 20 hours ago. (If it would have been an hour or less I wouldn't have bothered with the Q here)